# Rails joins on has_many with no or 0 count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Models: 
`User` has_many `posts`, `post` belongs to `user`

I'm looking to find users without any published posts.

I tried:

```
User.joins(:posts).where(posts: { published: true }).group('users.id').having('count(posts.id) = 0')
```

But I'm guessing `posts.id` is null when user doesn't have a published post, so its not return any user records.

When I do more than 0, `'count(posts.id) > 0'`, its working correctly. Is there another SQL method I can use instead of `count`?

Comment: `.joins` gives a `INNER LEFT JOIN` - so rows in the `users` table with no match in `posts` will not be returned. What you want is an outer join. In Rails 5 you can use `.left_outer_joins` - in previous versions you would use a [custom SQL string with joins](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html).

Comment: But `User.where.not(id: Post.where(published: true).pluck(:user_id))` is far simpler if you can live with two queries.

Comment: @max As I see, we answered simultaneously :) But in my solution I suggest `.select` instead of `.pluck` to have only one query instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested on Rails 5.0.2 with Postgres 9.6**

You can try this query:

```
User.where.not(id: Post.where(published: true).distinct.select(:user_id))
```

The output SQL will be like this:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT posts.user_id FROM posts WHERE posts.published = true
)
```

Note that this query will also include users than don't have any posts. If you don't want to load such users, you can modify a query like this:

```
User.where.not(id: Post.where(published: true).distinct.select(:user_id))
  .where('EXISTS (SELECT user_id from posts WHERE user_id = users.id)')
```

The output SQL will be like this:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT posts.user_id FROM posts WHERE posts.published = true
) AND EXISTS (SELECT user_id from posts WHERE user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: `User.where.not(id: Post.where(published: true).distinct.select(:user_id)).count == 0`
`
`User.where.not(id: Post.where(published: true).pluck(:user_id)).count == 3454`
so pluck works, `select.distinct` doesns't work, it doesn't return an array or user_ids

Comment: @neo Could you provide an output queries of both solutions, with `.pluck` and `.select`? Cause in my case I have the same result of `.count`.

Comment: Or, better, separate result of `Post.where(published: true).distinct.select(:user_id)`.

Comment: The SQL queries for `.select` and for `.pluck` should be similar, except that `.pluck` fires query immediately and returns an array. And `.select` in that case influences the entire output SQL query. And could you also try without `.distinct`?

Comment: you're gonna need to do `Post.where(published: true).distinct.select(:user_id).map(&:user_id)` to extract the user ids, it comes back to two queries

Comment: @neo It's possible to make it with one query. I have a Rails 5.0.2 with postgres 9.6. I execute queries from my answer in Rails console and everything works. The produced SQL and result is correct. It gives the same result as solution with `.pluck`, but with only one query. I just want to understand why it doesn't work in your case.

Comment: It could be rails versions, I'm on 4.2.5